# Node.js http.request Results Back as Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, express

All,

I am trying to figure out how to pass the results from an https.request in node.js code out to a variable. I have an https.request setup that correctly passes the correct information to a SOAP API and gets the correct response back. My ultimate goal is to get the output from the https.request into a variable that I can call using Express.

Here is are my code chunks.

HTML:

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" class="pull-left">
                    <p> TEST </p>
                    <p>{{soapreply}}</p>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
  app.post('/cucmmapper/submit', function (req, res) {
// FORM - DATA COLLECTION
var cucmpub = req.body.cucmpub;
var cucmversion = req.body.cucmversion;
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
var authentication = username + ":" + password;
var soapreplyx = '';

// SOAP - BUILD CALL
var https = require("https");
var headers = {
  'SoapAction': 'CUCM:DB ver=' + cucmversion + ' listCss',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authentication).toString('base64'),
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
};

// SOAP - AXL CALL
var soapBody = new Buffer('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">' +
  '<soapenv:Header/>' +
  '<soapenv:Body>' +
  '<ns:listCss sequence="?">' +
  '<searchCriteria>' +
  '<name>%</name>' +
  '</searchCriteria>' +
  '<returnedTags uuid="?">' +
  '<name>?</name>' +
  '<description>?</description>' +
  '<clause>?</clause>' +
  '</returnedTags>' +
  '</ns:listCss>' +
  '</soapenv:Body>' +
  '</soapenv:Envelope>');

// SOAP - OPTIONS
var options = {
  host: cucmpub, // IP ADDRESS OF CUCM PUBLISHER
  port: 8443, // DEFAULT CISCO SSL PORT
  path: '/axl/', // AXL URL
  method: 'POST', // AXL REQUIREMENT OF POST
  headers: headers, // HEADER VAR
  rejectUnauthorized: false // REQUIRED TO ACCEPT SELF-SIGNED CERTS
};

// SOAP - Doesn't seem to need this line, but it might be useful anyway for pooling?
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

// SOAP - OPEN SESSION
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (d) {
    soapreplyx = d;
    console.log("Got Data: " + d);
  });
});

// SOAP - SEND AXL CALL
req.write(soapBody);
res.render('cucmmapper-results.html'), {
  'title': 'CUCM 2.1',
  'soapreply': soapreplyx
};
req.end();
req.on('error', function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

});
}

The line "console.log("Got Data: " + d)" is getting the correct expected reply from the API, however, I can't figure out how to get that data into my variable "soapreplyx" which changes in Express to "soapreply".

Much appreciated for any help you might have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not waiting for your request to respond before you call `res.render()`, so the value of `soapreplyx` is always `''`, its initial value. To correct this, add an `'end'` event listener on the response object passed to your `https.request()` callback.

You're not appending the chunks of the response to your `soapreplyx` variable, you're reassigning its value with each successive chunk.

```
let soapRequest = https.request(options, soapResponse => {
  soapResponse.on('data', chunk => {
    soapreplyx += chunk
  })

  soapResponse.on('end', () => {
    return res.render('cucmmapper-results.html', {
      title: 'CUCM 2.1',
      soapreply: soapreplyx
    })
  })
})

soapRequest.write(soapBody)
soapRequest.end()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You hit the nail on the head. I got into the weeds and couldn't see my way back out. Thanks so much for your time helping me!